# function imported from react context does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently attempting to do a fairly low-level Typescript migration for my React app. The app itself uses context, in which it defines various functions and exports them to be used elsewhere when needed.

Here's my 'DataContext' file:

```
export const DataContext = React.createContext({})

export const DataProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {

    const fetchAll = async (userId: string) => {

        // Function here

    }

    return (
        <DataContext.Provider value={{ fetchAll }}>
            { children }
        </DataContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

However, when I try to import this file into another Typescript file, I get the following error:

> Property 'fetchAll' does not exist on type '{}'

I'm assuming this is because on my 'createContext' I'm using an empty object. But is there another way for me to do it, and is this creating my error?

Here's my file importing the 'fetchAll' function in this case:

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'

import { DataContext } from '../../context/DataContext'

type Props = {
    text: string,
    subcontent: string,
    id: string
}

export const Pending = ({ text, subcontent, id }: Props) => {

    const { fetchAll } = useContext(DataContext)

    // I use fetchAll in a useEffect, but removed it for simplicity

    return (
        // Component here...
    )
}
```

Any advice / pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the type of your context in order to be able to retrieve `fetchAll`

```
export const DataContext = React.createContext<{
   fetchAll: (userId: string) => Promise<WhateverIsTheReturnType>
}>(null)
```

Then I would set up an hook to retrieve the context value like this

```
const useDataContext = () => {
  const value = useContext(DataContext)
  if (value === null) {
    throw new Error(
      '`DataContext` should always have `DataProvider` as a parent component',
    )
  }

  return value
}
```

So then you can just use it like this `const {fetchAll} = useDataContext()`